# D3 … when to use recursive function vs nest?

Tags: javascript, csv, recursion, d3.js

I have two counties.  Each county has two schools in it. They're in a tabular CSV.
I want to create a map of counties, color each one for its graduation rate, then when you click on a school system, you see a list of the schools in it & each school's graduation rate. (Geography for individual schools is not available.)

I'm thinking I want to create a .json like this:

```
[{"county": "Fulton County", "weighted_graduation_rate": 91,
    "geography": // A bunch of geoJson here, 
    "children": [{"school_name":"North Fulton", "graduation_rate": 88}
                 {"school_name":"South Fulton", "graduation_rate": 92}
                ]
  }{
  "county": "Cobb County", "weighted_graduation_rate": 85,
    "geography": // A bunch of geoJson here,  
    "children": [{"school_name":"North Cobb", "graduation_rate": 88}
                 {"school_name":"South Cobb", "graduation_rate": 78}
                ]
}]
```

Or put another way:

```
                                               / North Fulton, graduation rate 88
 Fulton County School System, weighted graduation rate 91, geography 
   /                                           \South Fulton, graduation rate 92
counties
    \                                         / North Cobb, graduation rate 88
 Cobb County School System, weighted graduation rate 85, geography
                                              \South Cobb, graduation rate 78
```

Original csv:

```
county, school_name, graduation_rate
Fulton County, North Fulton, 88
Fulton County, South Fulton, 92
Fulton County, mean all schools, 91
Cobb County, North Cobb, 78
Cobb County, South Cobb, 88
Cobb County, mean all schools, 85
```

Here's the rub:

If I nest by county, each county has three children: the north school, the south school and the county average.

So I'm going to have to go with something more complex, but I don't know what.

Each county has to have system geography and an array holding its child schools.

I can't delete the data for "all schools", because it's weighted. The weight of each school is not available. So I have to call on that.  I can't calculate it later.

Is there a way to flenagle this by nest?  Or need to go with recursion?

Comment: Recursive functions are usually  used, when you don't know, how deep you're going to iterate in each branch. If you know, you can use nested loops as well.

Comment: Hm, then I think the best way is not to do it client side. Just clean it up once on my end.